# Returning an empty vector of strings if key is not found

Tags: c++, stl, vector, return-value, stdvector

I know it is a very bad idea, so other suggestions on how to do it efficiently will be well-received.

Here's the thing. I have `map<string,vector<string> >` , I want to search for a key and return its corresponding value (vector of strings in this case). Reason I insist on returning (rather than just iterating) is I need to search the values returned in some other vector.

An example will make this clear:

```
Input:

key1 ---> {2,3,4}
key2 ---> {1}
key3 ---> {2,12,11,9}
```

For key1 as input, vector with values 2,3,4 should be returned. Now these 2,3,4 values need to be searched in other vector of strings. What is the most efficient way to do this?

I tried something like this:

```
vector<string> returnEdges(string key)
{
    for (map<string, vector<string> >::iterator it=outgoing.begin();
    it!=outgoing.end();++it)
    {
        if (key.compare((*it).first)==0)
        {
            return (*it).second;
        }
    }


    //return string<;//what should I return here????


}
```

1) How should I return empty vector in case key is not found?

2) what is the best way to implement this?

I hope the question is clear.

EDIT: As I wrote the question, I thought why not return an iterator? Do the people at SO give their approval for this idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Returning an iterator is a fine idea. When you do this, the natural way to indicate the "not found" case is to return the .end() iterator. This has the down-side that the abstraction is somewhat leaky: the caller has to be able to get at this .end() value in order to compare to it for error checking, and the returned iterator exposes a richer interface than you'd like (the client code shouldn't really play around with incrementing and decrementing the iterator).

2) Returning an empty vector is as simple as creating an empty vector and returning it. Creating an empty vector = constructing a vector which is empty. This is what you get from - drum roll - the default constructor of the vector class.

3) You don't need to, and shouldn't, implement the search loop yourself. The standard library already implements this for you. (There is a specialized `find` function for `map` s because of the key/value distinction. For sequences like `list`, `vector` and `deque`, prefer the free function `std::find`, which comes from `<algorithm>`.

4) You should prefer to accept function parameters (when they are instances of classes, like `std::string`) and return data (especially complex things like a vector of strings) by const reference. Passing and returning by value implies a copy; sometimes the compiler can optimize this away, but it's not as reliable as we'd like. Besides, the reason you're using C++ in the first place is to have that level of control over things, right? If not, then don't torture yourself with it.

However, you can't do that if you're going to return a newly-created value some of the time. Yet another way to design the interface is to return a **pointer** to the vector of strings (note that pointer arithmetic on these will be invalid) within the map, or a NULL pointer if the value is not found. This avoids copying and distinguishes a "not found" result from an actual empty vector within the data, but it means the client code has to deal with an icky raw pointer.

5) Having 'return' in the name of a function is useless, as returning is what functions do. OTOH, it is a good idea to name things in a way that makes it evident why the parameters are what they are.

6) With iterators for complex types, it is often a good idea to set up typedefs.

Returning an iterator is as simple as:

```
typedef map<string, vector<string> >::iterator graph_iterator;
graph_iterator edges_named(const string& node_name) {
    return outgoing.find(node_name);
}
```

Returning a vector of strings is as simple as:

```
typedef map<string, vector<string> >::iterator graph_iterator;
vector<string> edges_named(const string& node_name) {
    graph_iterator it = outgoing.find(node_name);
    return it == outgoing.end() ? vector<string>() : it->second;
}
```

Returning a pointer is as simple as:

```
typedef map<string, vector<string> >::iterator graph_iterator;
vector<string>* edges_named(const string& node_name) {
    graph_iterator it = outgoing.find(node_name);
    return it == outgoing.end() ? NULL : &(it->second);
}
```

Choose wisely.

Comment: I feel a bit queasy about those raw pointers. Maybe that design could be useful, but somehow there should be a better way. The OP is invited to explain her goals; maybe we can suggest something specific.

Comment: @Karl, Awesome awesome answer. I think these are the problems many people like me , who come from other languages to C++ face and not able to use it efficiently / effectively

Comment: Converting iterators to raw pointers is a way to restrict the interface. However, it still doesn't prevent incrementing/decrementing - it just means that it'll break (undefined behaviour that is **expected** to crash in normal circumstances, but who really knows) instead of letting the user break encapsulation into itty bitty pieces. Probably a better idea is to create a wrapper class - a kind of deliberately-dumb smart pointer. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
std::vector<std::string> find_by_key_maybe(const std::string & key)
{
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>::const_iterator it = themap.find(key);
  return it == themap.end() ? std::vector<std::string>() : it->second;
}
```

Or even, if `themap` is non-const, and you also wish to add an empty vector into the map:

```
std::vector<std::string> find_by_key_and_insert_if_missing(const std::string & key)
{
  return themap[key];
}
```

It's perfectly OK to return a vector by value, if that's what the situation calls for.

Comment: Note that using `themap[key]` will also add an empty vector to the map under that key. Depending on your exact application, this can range from incredibly useful to completely unacceptable, and everywhere in between.

Comment: @Karl: Hah, yes - I should add this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. what about returning iterator? isn't that more efficient ? (I may be wrong here though)

Comment: @Karl, so if I am definitely sure the key is there, it should be ok,am I right?

Comment: Returning the iterator means that you get to skip creating empty vectors and potentially throwing them away. You also get to skip copying the returned vectors. However, in some cases, the compiler may be able to elide that copy. Also, if you take the `return themap[key]` approach, you can also return by const reference and avoid the copy that way.

Comment: If you are "sure" the key is there, then the correct way to deal with the "not found" case is to throw an exception. After all, you want everything to fail-fast if your expectations are not met, right?

Comment: @Anon: I'm not entirely sure what would be best, because I don't know what you're doing. As it stands, the `find` call is already just one line, so you might as well just integrate that into your code elsewhere and do away with the function entirely. Returning an single iterator is only useful if you also have access to the container at the call site. (Returning a *pair* of iterators, on the other hand, is useful even without knowledge of any container, but that's an entirely different matter.)

Comment: @Anon: There's way too little information in your question, in my opinion. You asked how to return an empty vector, so I assumed that you may have need for one. If you're really after something else, you should say that, and I have a feeling that there'll be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you just "integrate the find" call and dereference the iterator without checking because you're "sure" the key is there, you won't get a nice friendly exception if you're wrong - you'll get undefined behaviour. Of course, the return-a-raw-pointer approach causes UB if the client code does pointer arithmetic, but then at least you know it's the client code's fault ;)

Comment: @Karl: Since the integration would supposedly place the `find` result in the same scope as the container, I figured that you'd perform an `!= end()` check right there. I think that's a fairly common pattern... you can react to the "not found" situation at the call site however appropriate.

Comment: why on earth I cannot accept 2 answers? Both are equally good. Thank you so much for your help. Means a lot to me. One day, I wish I have as much knowledge as you guys do.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you don't need a copy of the vector to be returned, a const reference will do just as well. You can always make a copy later if you need to.

Also you don't need to iterate through a map, they're optimized for searching with the `find` method.

```
const vector<string> & returnEdges(string key)
{
    map<string, vector<string> >::iterator it = outgoing.find(key);
    if (it == outgoing.end())
    {
        static vector<string> empty_vector;
        return empty_vector;
    }
    return it->second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the operator [] can help you, it will return a empty value(a empty vector here).
So all you need to do is

```
vector<string> returnEdges(string key) 
{
    return outgoing[key];
}
```

Comment: As we already discussed above, this also *inserts* an empty value into the map, which may or may not be desirable.